# Factory class to handle logic of a constructor?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have a Maze class which has a constructor:

```
public class Maze implements MazeInterface {

  private int width;          // Width of maze in units
  private int height;         // Height of maze in units
  private long seed;          // Seed generated for the maze
  private Cell[][] board;     // 2D representation of the maze

  public Maze(int w, int h, Cell[][] maze, long s){
      width = w;
      height = h;
      board = maze;
      seed = s;
  }

  // Bunch of other methods/stuff irrelevant

}
```

I was reading online about good practices and now I understand that a complex constructor is bad practice. So I thought a factory class would be a viable solution. What I want to do is generate a random seed, random w/h values for the maze (how many units wide or tall the maze is), and other logic for the Maze object. Is the factory pattern the right way to do this?

```
public class MazeFactory {

  public Maze createMaze(){
      long s = generateSeed();       // Generation of a seed
      int w  = generateW();          // Random w value
      int h  = generateH();          // Random h value

      return new Maze(w, h, new Cell[w][h], s);
  }

  private long generateSeed(){
      // Do stuff and return a seed
  }

  private int generateW(){
      // Do stuff
  }

  private int generateH(){
      // Do stuff
  }

}
```

Would this separation of logic be beneficial by putting it into a Factory class or is this the wrong way to go about this (wrong pattern use/etc) or should I just do this within the Maze class in the constructor by writing private methods and calling them in the constructor? I am trying to learn about  different patterns/best practices, but I think i'm misunderstanding the way Factory design is handled or if I am just using the wrong pattern.

Comment: What's the difference? You still have your complex `Maze` constructor. All you've done is show us how you call it - you would have had something similar somewhere even if you didn't have the factory. Why are you passing the cells in? why doesn't the constructor create them?

Comment: There's a bug in your factory: in `createMaze()` you pass in `w` and `h` and you also declare them as local variables and assign them random values.

Comment: So I thought a complex constructor was a constructor that did too much or had too much logic. So I wanted to separate them and follow good practices. Doing what I did above, I thought it would make it "less" complex/more readable/maintainable. I read that constructors using the `new` keyword is bad practice so I didn't want to. There are way too many things that I'm reading about practices that get super confusing so I don't honestly know what is a better way of going about it.                                   @aro_tech I fixed that, I modified the code on the spot a bit and missed that!

Comment: I think it's a good approach to handle the random generation outside the constructor (a factory seems like a clean approach) but the `new Cell[w][h]` seems like it belongs in the constructor, as this array seems to be an internal detail of the Maze class implementation, and it's not especially complex.

Comment: I like sprinter's builder approach in general, but there is something unclear in your question. At what point do you populate your 2-D array of Cell objects?

Comment: @aro_tech That is a good question! I actually didn't put that info/code into this question yet to simplify the code for this question(would require loop with instantiation of Cell objects which I feel like might require its own method). But I do believe the builder pattern better suits the design, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is about when to use creational patterns https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern. This is a big a fairly complex topic with really no right and wrong answer. I'll provide my personal 'rules-of-thumb' but I'm sure there will be many contrary views.

The key advantage of a 'factory' pattern is that it separates the creation of an object from its operation. One of the triggers for this is when you don't know ahead of time which class you are creating. You can have a factory that generates a number of different classes depending on the method called. Note that this doesn't necessarily make the construtor any simpler.

The key advantage of a 'builder' pattern is that it breaks a complex constructor down into individual steps that can be varied by the user. This pattern can help when there are many variations on the creation or when you have many potential values that can be set which have sensible default values.

I would guess that a builder is more appropriate for your case. Your construction code might look something like:

```
Maze myMaze = mazeBuilder.makeMazeOfSize(30, 20).withBoard(values).withSeed(15).build();
```

This also has the advantage of documenting the meaning of the creation values.